# How to run Kafka Producer from console that I have written in Java?

Tags: java, compilation, apache-kafka

```
So i have a project in java which has this structure

   !![directory struct](http://postimg.org/image/vqn69s6tn/)
```

If I want to compile the TESTPROD.java, how should I do that as it has a lot of dependency on kafka`s scala files?

Answer (score 2):

(1). create a empty pom file (pom.xml)

> ```
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>   <groupId>demo</groupId>
>   <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
>   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
> ```

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka_2.8.0</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.0-beta1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

(2). fixed the error pom (bad)

~/.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka_2.8.0/0.8.0-beta1/kafka_2.8.0-0.8.0-beta1.pom

The pom file has a duplicate tag (dependencies), remove the first one and save it.

(3). fetch all the dependencies using maven

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

Now you can get all the dependencies in the directory:

```
➜ ~/Downloads/x $ ll target/dependency/
total 40424
-rw-r--r--  1 adyliu  staff    62K  9 13 16:48 activation-1.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 adyliu  staff    85K  9 13 16:48 jline-0.9.94.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 adyliu  staff    26K  9 13 16:48 jms-1.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 adyliu  staff   357K  9 13 16:48 jmxri-1.2.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 adyliu  staff   100K  9 13 16:48 jmxtools-1.2.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 adyliu  staff    52K  9 13 16:48 jopt-simple-3.2.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 adyliu  staff   118K  9 13 16:48 junit-3.8.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 adyliu  staff   2.3M  9 13 16:40 kafka_2.8.0-0.8.0-beta1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 adyliu  staff   383K  9 13 16:48 log4j-1.2.15.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 adyliu  staff   380K  9 13 16:48 mail-1.4.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 adyliu  staff   4.1K  9 13 16:48 metrics-annotation-2.2.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 adyliu  staff    80K  9 13 16:48 metrics-core-2.2.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 adyliu  staff   8.3M  9 13 16:48 scala-compiler-2.8.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 adyliu  staff   5.9M  9 13 16:48 scala-library-2.8.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 adyliu  staff    25K  9 13 16:48 slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 adyliu  staff   7.5K  9 13 16:48 slf4j-simple-1.6.4.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 adyliu  staff   973K  9 13 16:48 snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 adyliu  staff    63K  9 13 16:48 zkclient-0.3.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 adyliu  staff   590K  9 13 16:48 zookeeper-3.3.4.jar
```